# ERROR attaching adventureworks2012_data.mdf file with sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express, adventureworks

I have been trying to add adventure works database to my SQL server 2012..I tried to attach the database using SQL Server Management Studio as follows: I Right Clicked  on Databases > Attach and clicked  Add... > selected the AdventureWorks2012_Data file.  and then I Selected the log file and removed the log file by clicking on the Remove button then clicked OK but I still get an error that the header file is not a valid database header file and the FILESIZE property is incorrect ......please help me

Comment: Try downloading it again.  Sounds like it may be corrupt download.

Comment: i also seem to be missing MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER folder in the C:\Program Files\Microsoft sql Server path .... can you help me with this also..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Martin suggested, it may be that the file you downloaded is incorrect. You should [download a new copy from here](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330) (I wouldn't get it anywhere else):

> [image]

Once you do, don't use the UI for this. Make sure you copy the .mdf file to your instance's data folder. Then run this code in a query window:

```
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
  ON (name = 'AdventureWorks2012_data', 
  filename = 'drive:\path\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG;
```

You will get this "error" message:

> File activation failure. The physical file name "drive:\path\AdventureWorks2012_Log.ldf" may be incorrect.

This is just SQL Server telling you that it didn't find the log file; it should still create one for you unless you have other issues (permission denied, lack of space, the same name file already exists, etc).